# Is there any available assessment of relative capabilities of Claude-2 and GPT-4?

Tags: comparison

My first experience with Claude-2 indicates that it has capabilities well comparable to GPT-4 and noticably above those of GPT-3.5.

There is an [AI models ladder](https://chat.lmsys.org/) but it currently does not include Claude-2. In the ladder Claude-1 is rated above GPT-3.5 but below GPT-4.